# ios 5 subview flip between two view in tableview cell

Tags: iphone, ios5, tableview

I have tableview which contains custom cell. 
Each cell has view that I want to flip when user click on that row. I successfully made it work for this one. But the point I struggle with is when user clicks on other row, I want to flip back to original view for previous cell and flip currently clicked row.

here is some code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CustomCell *selectedCell = 
        (CustomCell *)[self.AlbumViewTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.current_index];
//if other row is already flipped then make it back to original state.
if(otherRowIsFlipped){
    selectedCell.defaultImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultIndecator.jpg"]];
    selectedCell.defaultImage = CGRectMake(0, 0, 43, 43);
    [self flipView:selectedCell.flipViewContainer From:selectedCell.activity To:selectedCell.defaultImage];
}

CustomCell * new_row = 
        (CustomCell *)[self.AlbumViewTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


new_row.activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
new_row.activity.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 43, 43);
[new_row.activity startAnimating];

 //this method is merely called UIView subroutine to flip between two view 
[self flipView:new_row.flipViewContainer From:new_row.defaultImage To:new_row.activity];

[self.AlbumViewTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I was able to flip back previously selected row and flip currently selected row, yet I found  weird thing that when I scroll down tableview and flip view appeared on a row which has never been selected.

I tried to make properties in CustomCell class and attempted to flip but no luck too. 
I'm not sure this approach is correct but it seems to work unless I scroll down to 
load other rows.

I'd appreciate for any advices. Thanks

Comment: you should show some code....

Comment: - (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition;
- (void)deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated; use these delegates

Comment: show some code for more response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a custom TableViewCell with such view structure

```
-CELL
--CONTENT_VIEW
---1st_side
---2nd_side
```

and the code is

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7f];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:containerView cache:NO];
  [firstView removeFromSuperview];
  [containerView addSubview:secondView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and the same for back method

Comment: CustomCell class structure is look like that. My question is, when you remove view from superview, I believe it will automatically free its memory. So should I alloc a heap again when I attempt to swipe it again?

Comment: And again, some other cells somehow share flipped view when I scroll down to other cells. That is other cell's subview appears as flipped view but it never has been clicked. I guess its because it uses reusable cell?

Comment: Views should be a properties of your cell. If they are they will stay in memory because of retaining in cell. Yes You should use -prepereForReuse method in cell to set the default state. And array of opened NSIndexPathes